# Add dynamic footer in MS Word using Apache POI - Java

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

Could someone please explain how to insert dynamic footer in each page using Apache poi API -  e.g. timestamp & Page Number

Answer (score 2):

Inserting footers is possible using [XWPFDocument.createFooter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#createFooter-org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType-). The `XWPFFooter`then has it's own body containng `XWPFParagraph`s and `XWPFRun`s.

To use dynamic content as time and page numbers one would insert fields into the paragraphs. This is not yet supported by `apache poi` in the `XWPF` classes. But if one knows what XML needs to be inserted, one could use the low level `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*` classes.

But how to know how the XML must look like?

A `*.docx` file, as well as all other `Offiche Open XML` files, is simply a ZIP archive. So one can unzip a `*.docx` file and have a look into. So create a `*.docx` file having what you need using the Word GUI. Then unzip that `*.docx` file and have a look into. The footers you will  find in `/word/footer*.xml` files. There you find something like that for fields:

```xml
...
<w:r>
 <w:t xml:space="preserve">Time: </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:fldSimple w:instr="TIME \@ "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" \* MERGEFORMAT"/>
<w:r>
 <w:tab/>
</w:r>
<w:r>
 <w:t xml:space="preserve">Page </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:fldSimple w:instr="PAGE \* MERGEFORMAT"/>
<w:r>
 <w:t xml:space="preserve"> of </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:fldSimple w:instr="NUMPAGES \* MERGEFORMAT"/>
...
```

Now the need is to create that using the `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*` classes.

Unfortunately there is no API documentation for the `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*` classes public available. So one would need getting the sources of `ooxml-schemas` or `poi-ooxml-full` to create the API documentation using `javadoc`.

Complete example which creates footers containg thme and page numbers:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;

public class CreateWordFooterTimestampPagenumbers {
    
 private static void addTabStop(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String type, double posInches) {
  int twipsPerInch = 1440; //measurement unit for tab stop pos is twips (twentieth of an inch point)
  long pos = Math.round(posInches * twipsPerInch);
  
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP cTP = paragraph.getCTP();
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPr cTPPr = cTP.getPPr();
  if (cTPPr == null) cTPPr = cTP.addNewPPr();
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTabs cTTabs = cTPPr.getTabs();
  if (cTTabs == null) cTTabs = cTPPr.addNewTabs();
  
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTabStop  cTTabStop = cTTabs.addNewTab();
  cTTabStop.setPos​(pos);
  
  switch(type) {
   case "LEFT": 
    cTTabStop.setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTabJc.LEFT);
    break;
   case "CENTER": 
    cTTabStop.setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTabJc.CENTER);
    break;
   case "RIGHT": 
    cTTabStop.setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTabJc.RIGHT);
    break;
   case "DECIMAL": 
    cTTabStop.setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTabJc.DECIMAL);
    break;
   case "BAR": 
    cTTabStop.setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTabJc.BAR);
    break;
   default:
    // simply do nothing
  }
  
 }
 
 private static void createDocFooter(XWPFDocument document) {

  XWPFFooter footer = document.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = footer.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
  addTabStop(paragraph, "CENTER", 3.25);
  
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Time: ");
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("TIME \\@ \"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss\" \\* MERGEFORMAT");
  
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.addTab();
  
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Page ");
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("PAGE \\* MERGEFORMAT");
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText(" of ");
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("NUMPAGES \\* MERGEFORMAT");
  
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  // the body content
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body:");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum.... page 1");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE); 
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum.... page 2");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE); 
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum.... page 3");

  createDocFooter(document);
  
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordFooterTimestampPagenumbers.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

This is tested and works using current `apache poi 5.2.2` and having `poi-ooxml-full-5.2.2.jar` in class-path.

Comment: Can i identify dynamic fields like page number when I import word document as XWPFDocument? As of now, it is coming as it is with the actual page number.